# How to define picturebox coordinate

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, picturebox, drawimage

I am trying to draw an image on top of another image in a picturebox. They are the same size (125X150). When I paint the second picture at point[0,0] in the picturebox, the two pictures do not line up.Here is my code:

```
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("picture\\faces\\face3.png");

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.DrawImage(new Bitmap("picture\\faces\\eyebow1.png"), new Point(0, 0));
        g.Dispose();
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: If you dont like where the second one draws, change it to use something other than `0, 0`

Comment: Do the image match in both size and dpi resolution? Do they hav th same size as the pbox.Clientsize? What is the SizeMode?

Comment: The picturebox is also 125X150, size mode is "Normal"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself. Although I do not know why:

```
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("picture\\faces\\face3.png");

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        Console.WriteLine(bmp.Width);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("picture\\faces\\eyebow1.png");
        g.DrawImage(new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image), new Point(0, 0));

        g.Dispose();
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```